# Can't define id in android studio

Tags: android

I can't define id anywhere,it is a strange question,my situation as followed.
who can help me? i am new to android development.
[image: can't define id]

[my xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRye4.png)

Comment: Could you post the entire xml file?

Comment: I have uploaded picture about my xml file,please refreshing your page,thinks for your comment.

Comment: can you add more information, like the line which causes the error/warning.

Comment: Please clicking link(my xml file) in my post to see entire information about my  xml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try the following:**
 File -> 'Invalidate Caches/Restart' and restart android studio.

Comment: I have tryed more than once by this way,but there have no effect.